# How can I confirm the presence of an HDMI signal with a slow scope?

Tags: signal, oscilloscope, hdmi

Per the title, I'm trying to troubleshoot a circuit and confirm if a device is putting out an HDMI signal but I only have access to "slow" (<=200MHz) oscilloscopes.

I don't need to know anything *about* the signal other than if it is present and is some sort of HDMI data as opposed to just idle/disabled pin states.

I've checked a working HDMI signal with the scope at maximum speed but it just aliases out to what looks like a steady voltage level.  Are there any tricks or things I can do to get past this?

EDIT: Resolution is 1920x1080p60 or smaller, so not 4K or anything like that. <300MHz clock I think.

Comment: What resolution are we talking about? To give an idea of what pixel clock speed might be used.

Comment: Updated question - <300MHz pixel clock I think, <=1920x1080p60 resolution.

Comment: An HDMI signal source device may not randomly output anything i.e. may first require some sort of "handshake" between the source and the target (e.g. EDID). `it just aliases out to what looks like a steady voltage level` this sounds like the common-mode voltage for the signal lines as the HDMI signals are differential. You may want to check the I2C pins at first power up. If there's any signalling then the source might be trying for something like enumeration or querying the target's capabilities.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I'm aware of that part, I'm trying to confirm if actual HDMI video data is passing.

Comment: What is the steady voltage level? Oh and use lowest possible resolution like 640x480, and your scope will be fine.

Comment: With 300 MHz BW you'll lose pretty much all the rising and falling edges which can be as low as a few tens to a few hundreds of picoseconds. What you can try is to use 1:1 probe with 50-Ohm termination and probe the CLOCK pair, or decrease the resolution and probe the same pair using the same probe config, as Justme suggested.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I strongly advice against putting a 50 ohm termination to ground on HDMI TMDS wires. They are supposed to be terminated with 50 ohms to 3.3V so you can't apply extra terminations to gnd.

Comment: @Justme We assume the cable has a 50-Ohm impedance, so effectively the signal source which has a 50-Ohm output impedance will be loaded with another 50-50 transmission line. Am I wrong? In this case, would it be a problem?

Comment: @RohatKılıç If the HDMI output is already connected to HDMI input, the TMDS lines float near 3.3V with 50 ohm terminations of the devices. You can't put a scope that terminates with 50 ohms to ground or you may damage something with excess current or differential voltage to HDMI input. Also if you only connect a scope instead of HDMI receiver, the scope is unable to provide 50 ohm termination to 3.3V so you can't see a thing. Standard 10:1 scope probe is just fine for checking if there is video or not.

Comment: @Justme what I've been trying to say is [this](https://i.imgur.com/z87yz3i.png). HDMI TMDS is a current-mode logic so that's why the lines are terminated to 3V3 with 50 Ohms. Now with the configuration I showed in the image the 3V3 source on target-side will be loaded more, yes. But reflection-wise there won't be any problems. Using a standard 10:1 probe may create some reflection problems.

Comment: @RohatKılıç That will pull the DC bias of one wire of differential pair to out-of-any-sane-operating level. The differential receiver will just see a flat line, and source may see that voltage is not near 3.3V so cable may be unplugged.

Comment: @Justme I showed only one line, of course should be applied on both lines (Yes, I should've mentioned). That's why I said `probe the pair` in my first comment. Yes, the DC bias will shift but the swing (when applied on both lines) will be ~900 mV which is still within the required 800-1200 mV range.

Comment: @Justme we don't have control of the resolution, it's as I said - 1920x1080p60 or below but I can't change it to suit my testing.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes, so DC bias will shift, and then it will be out of required input common mode voltage range for normal operation, so it does not have to work.